# Python a handy way to mock/patch only "top-level" / first call to object

Tags: python

Firstly the code:

```
class Foo:

    ...
    def apply_* ...
    ...

    def apply_all(self, ) -> None:
        self.apply_goal_filter()
        self.apply_gender_filter()
        self.apply_age_filter()
        ...  # Many apply_*
```

To test this function I should mock every `apply_*` method in class and call `assert_called` on it.
Is I can do it automatically and wrap my class somehow to mock all except top level calls?
I.E.:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.apply_all()  # The real call to method
# Inside "foo.apply_all"
self.apply_goal_filter()  # Mock call
self.apply_gender_filter()  # Mock call

# Another example:

Foo = Mock(...)
Foo.top_level_call  #  bound method ...
Foo.top_level_call.second_level_call  #  Mock object ...
```

Most likely I should patch `self/cls` somehow.
The workaround is call class method rather than instance method and pass `self` manually but it will not help for classmethods.
`Mock(wraps=foo)` will not help because it's wraps the object and executing all the calls.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I refreshed my knowledge of python metaprogramming and come to this solution

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = True
        self.mock = Mock()

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        exclude = []  # Just for convenience
        flag = object.__getattribute__(self, 'flag')
        # A "startswith" check may be improved with lookup in standard object, parent object, etc.
        if flag or item in exclude or item.startswith('__'): 
            # Attempt to access the attribute directly will cause an infinite recursion
            result = object.__getattribute__(self, item)  # AttributeError if not found
            setattr(self, 'flag', False)  # Assign only if attribute not exists in parent classes?  
            return result
        return object.__getattribute__(self, 'mock').item
```

Comment: `if flag or item in exclude` did you mean `if any(x in exclude for x in (flag, item))`?